# Spring Boot Security Authentication: Application having 2 different domain URL and need to authenticate with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need help with one of the issue that I am facing with Spring Boot Security. I have application which has 2 different Urls.(Infoblock CNAME)

1. domain1.com
2. domain2.com

both Url are point to the same application.

Due to business reason we need 2 different Url and we are planning to land on diff page based on the URL entered in browser. Issue is with Spring Security AntMatcher. 
**With AntMatcher we can only provide path but how we can address the domain with it**.

Could you please guide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of AntMatcher you can use

```
 http.requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Host", "127.0.0.1:8080"))
```

with any other `matcher` from `org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher` package.

Here is an example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter   {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class SecConfig1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Host", "127.0.0.1:8080"))
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
            .and()
                    .formLogin();
        }
    }
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class SecConfig2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Host", "127.0.0.2:8080"))
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //default deny all
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().denyAll();
    }
}
```